# Local maxima of the sum of Gaussian functions in *one dimension* are always strict local maxima - proof?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, st.statistics, nonlinear-optimization, gaussian

Motivated by [this question asked earlier](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452275/global-maximum-of-a-sum-of-gaussians), I was wondering whether one can prove easily that the local maxima of the sum of Gaussians:

$$f_n(x):= \sum_{i=1}^{n}e^{-(x-x_i)^2}, \quad x_1 < x_2 < \dots < x_n$$

are always **strict local maxima, i.e. there's a punctured neighborhood $U^*$ around each local maximum $x^*$, so that the  $\forall x \in U^*, f(x)< f(x^*),$ (instead of $f(x)\le f(x^*).$)**

I don't know of any *analytical expression* for the local maxima of the sum of Gaussians.

Of course when $n=1$, one can show that the unique local and global maximum is $x_1$. For $n=3$, I took $x_1= 1, x_2=5, x_3=8,$ and I [got](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) the following graph:

[image]

which clearly shows that the local maxima happen near the $x_i$'s (but not necessarily at the $x_i$'s). It also seems from the graph that my intuition is correct: **all local maxima of the sum of Gaussians are indeed strict local maxima**. But I was wondering whether there's a rigorous proof?

I guess one way to proceed might be by first observing that when $x< x_1$ or $x> x_n, f_n(x) > 0, f'(x) < 0$ respectively. **So this means that we just need to show that when $x \in [x_1, x_n], f(x)$ is at most a $2n$-to-$1$ function, i.e. the preimage of any point can have at most $2n$ elements** (this is intuitively thought out by the fact that for $n=1, f_1(x)$ is even, and for $n=3, f_3(x)$ is at most a $6$-to-$1$ function, and same behavior is observed for other values of $n$. Once proved, this will show that all local maxima of $f$ are indeed strict, as otherwise, it'd contradict that the preimage $f_n^{-1}(y), y \in \mathbb{R}$ of any $y$ can have at most $2n$ elements.  But I'm not sure how to show this...Next step will be to generalize it to multiple dimensions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The derivative $f'_n$ of $f_n$ is a nonzero real-analytic (and even entire) function. Therefore, $f'_n$ can have only finitely many zeroes in any bounded interval. So, all the local maxima of $f_n$ are isolated and therefore strict.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer. Just to understand this part better: "Therefore, $f_n'$ can have only finitely many zeroes in any bounded interval", is this the explanation? $f_n'$ is analytic, so if it vanishes infinite number of times on a closed interval $[a,b],$ it must have an accumulation point. But that means $f_n'$ is identically zero by identity theorem for real analytic functions - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem. So $f_n$ is a constant. But since $f_n$ is not constant, this can't happen. Hence $f_n'$ must have only finite number of zero on $[x_1, x_n].$

Comment: It seems to me that in higher dimensions so $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$, if we replace $(x-x_i)^2$ by $||x-x_i||^2,$ $f_n$ will still have all its local maxima strict local maxima. But I think the identity theorem may not apply to higher dimensions, as the zeros don't need to be isolated there...

Comment: Is there a reason to believe it to be true in higher dimensions? If we have a single Gaussian, it is radial, and therefore your property fails. This argument no longer works for a non-trivial sum, but the behavior does seem somewhat different.

Comment: @Mark: sorry I didn't quite understand what you meant by my property failing for a single Gaussian in higher dimensions. A single Gaussian would be of the form $e^{-||x-x_1||}^2,$ and would be maximized only at $x=x_1,$ and no other point, right? So even in this case, the single Gaussian will have only one strict local and also global maxima. P.S. if you meant the property of $2n$ to $1,$ then no, but it'll be replaced by a disjoint union of maximum $2n$ hyperspheres. Not sure if we need Morse theory etc. to show a result like this...

Comment: @Mark Furthermore, for a linear combination of Gaussians (mixture models), the function has a graphs like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcOHy.png, implying that the linear combinations of Gaussians most probably have only strictly local maxima.

Comment: @Learningmath : I suggest you ask the question about higher dimensions in a separate post.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I'll certainly do so now.

Comment: @IosifPinelis I just asked it here - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/440308/local-maxima-of-the-sum-of-gaussian-functions-in-higher-dimensions-are-always

Comment: @Learningmath : I will have this in mind. At this point, I don't have good ideas about higher dimensions.